# Why is my Pleco turning white, how to improve his health

Tags: health, aquarium, pleco

A few days ago I got a Pleco and some cherry shrimp for my aquarium. Due to my being a complete idiot, the bag with the Pleco fell while I was acclimating the shrimp. In order to keep it alive I put it directly into the aquarium.

Obviously this was about the worst start the little guy could have had, but the first 5 days he seemed okay, his color was starting to come back. However, he has not eaten anything and today I find him right at the glass, not moving, almost white.

The water is clean, I did a 20% waterchange yesterday, temp is at 24 c. Is there anything I can do to help it?

Comment: please edit the readings of your last water test into your question.plecos do get pale if they are stressed,so to give you an answer a bit more information about the water is needed.

Comment: Sadly it died on the same day I posted this:( Water params seemed all fine to me, no measurable nitrates/nitrites, ph at 7.1, no chlorines. Also the shrimps are breeding, which  they wouldn't do if conditions weren't good. I fear the stress or injury from me dropping it might have been what killed it:(

Comment: you are probably right,fish can get internal injury from even a small drop.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your setup, but one important detail about plecostomus (if I remember it correctly) is that they prefer dark places, as well as places to hide. If they do not have these conditions met, they might suffer from the stress, with any number of direct or side effects.

If you pay more attention, you might notice that they are more active during the night, when there is no movement in the room.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure but it can be due to direct sun light
So if that is the case try moving it in another area that doesnt have the sun burning it and they may get sunburns, And if thats not the case then i hope you find the answer.